# PHP custom session mechanism - and cookie expire problem

Tags: php, session

I'm using `session_set_save_handler()` to keep my session in Redis, and everything works perfectly, except one thing.
after hours and hours of pulling my hair I thought I should just ask someone.
so, on the server side, I set the session life for X minutes. on each page refresh, the session life is set to X minutes, but on the browser the cookie expires after exactly 30 minutes after the first page load. how can I force the cookie life to be extended on each page refresh like on the server side.
any thoughts?

Comment: Not as answer, but as variant: don't use default PHP session mechanism if you not satisfied with abilities. You can create little class to handle storing and fetching sessions from storage (Redis, Memcache, APC). It's really easy - session it's just little array. *Maybe I will put my code for sessions handling to github, if it could help to somebody :)*

Comment: @OZ_ Sounds reasonable, but could you please note why one shouldn't use PHP's sessions? Thanks.

Comment: @Wiseguy, I don't mean "PHP's sessions is bad", I mean "you can easily create your own". Only this.

Comment: @OZ_ - I totally agree with you, that's why I use my own, with Redis.Have encountered this problem?

Comment: @Michael, well, if you use your own session handler, then with each session storing you can refresh cookies, without using `session_start` and other related functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), strtotime('NOW+30MINUTES'));
```

Comment: this seems to work, thanks. but it takes a few precious microseconds, isn't there another way?

Comment: @Michael: You're kidding right? That would be premature micro-optimization.

Comment: well, I'm very thorough, that's why I ended up using redis on the first place :-)

Comment: @Michael: So you expect your program to magically extend the session cookie. I don't have any magic skills, sorry. :)

Comment: no, I just expected PHP to handle this somehow, on a low-level.
but I guess I can do further optimizations at a later time, meanwhile I recommend Redis for this purpose to anyone

Comment: 10 years later, this is the funniest dialog I have ever seen on StackOverflow. I can't believe I am the first person to ever upvote this.